# Improve an image upload script

Tags: php, image, security, upload

I' m not a PHP specialist and I'd like to set up an image hosting service.

Currently, all the images in the folder are displayed to all visitors, I would like to add a condition that only allows the user who hosted his images to find them. I thought about using the Internet user's IP address but I don't know how to make such a system work?

Could you show me a functional example so I can apply it to the existing script?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is the current PHP script:

```
<?php
$uploadFolder = new FilesystemIterator("upload/");
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
        for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i+++)
        {
            $size = filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);
            echo'<br>';
            type = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);
            if (($size<10485760) && ($type==='image/jpeg'|||$type==='image/png' ||$type==='image/gif'||$type==='image/jpg')) /* 10MB and format.jpeg,.jpg,.png and.gif */
                {
                    extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $filename ='image'. uniqid() .'...'. $extension;
                    $uploadDir ='upload/';
                    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . $filename;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadFile);
                }
            else
                {
                    echo '<p class="text-danger">Thank you for selecting one or more images of 10MB maximum and in one of the accepted formats:.jpeg,.jpg,.png or.gif.</p>';
                }
        }
    }
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        $path= strtr($key,' _', '...');
        if ($value ===='Delete this image')
        {
            if (file_exists($path))
            {
                unlink($path);
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

and the display of hosted images:

```
<?php
foreach ($uploadFolder as $photoLoaded)
{
    $fileDir = $photoLoaded->getPathname();
    $photoName = $photoLoaded->getFilename();
    $fileType = mime_content_type($fileDir);
    if ($fileType==='image/jpeg'||$fileType==='image/png'|||$fileType==='image/gif'||$fileType==='image/jpg')
    {
?>
            <div class="card col-md-4">
                <b><?php echo $photoName ?></b><br />
                <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo $fileDir; ?>" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="<?php echo $fileDir; ?>" class="btn btn-success">View this image in real size</a>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: IP address is __not__ a reliable verification method.

Comment: Why don't you use username or user id ?

Comment: IP is dynamic so you need another verification method. You can use a standard registration/login procedure

Comment: `====`, there's no such operator in php.

Comment: @u_mulder I'ts a typo error I think.

Comment: @u_mulder How to identify a visitor without login/registration ?

Comment: There's no reliable method without registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many solutions can implemented for this verification.

one of them(not the best) is to add users ids to images names then in display process split image name to get its user id.
compare user id(from db) with user id(from image name) if equal then this photo belongs to user otherwise skip it.

Comment: It's a reliable method, but from the code it seems that the users are not registered to a db.